# dots in rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes, user-profile

I'm trying to add a show page to my devise users but can't seem to get the id value passed properly, how do I create a link to the show page? For some reason rails is doing this to URL
     /show.1

users controller:

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

user/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>
```

link to user profile also gives me issues id no method

```
<%= link_to @post.email, users_show_path(@user.id) %>
```

routes.rb

```
 get "users/show"
 get "pages/faq"
 get "pages/about"
 devise_for :users
 resources :posts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the show route as:

```
get "users/show"
```

Notice that there is no dynamic segment in this route, like `:id`. That means your route is not expecting any value to be passed. BUT while linking to this route you passed `@user.id`

```
<%= link_to @post.email, users_show_path(@user.id) %>
```

which the route was not expecting. So, Rails assumed that you are passing the `format` (like `.html`, `.json`, etc.) which is why you see the url formed as `users/show.1`.

To fix this, I would suggest you to add a dynamic segment to your route to capture the `id` of a user correctly.

**Change**

```
 get "users/show"
```

**With**

```
 get "users/show/:id" => "users#show", as: :users_show
```

For a user with `id = 1`, when you click on the user profile link the url generated would be `http://yourdomain/users/show/1`

Comment: I fixed it by adding `resources :users`  below `devise for :users` but it only work when I have a link `current_user.id` if I put `@user.id` i get no method error, and `@post.username` I get `couldn't find user with id=dexter`

Comment: This advice helped me a lot!